# How to sync two *local* branches

Tags: git

**UPDATE** I have two (2) *local* Git **branches** (development and master) in one (1) repository.  Develop is up to date with the current working copy, master is not.  How do I get the two of them in sync?  I'm using SourceTree but don't see anyway of doing this with that -- is the command line the only way of doing it, or ?  If only the command line, what is the command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
git checkout development
git merge master
```

OR

```
git checkout development
git rebase master
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ask the question correctly... please see UPDATE above>

Comment: Based on your updated question, I think Isaac's answer is correct, you need to merge the two branches.

Comment: will *git merge develop/master* merge the LOCAL develop into the LOCAL master?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply checkout the branch you want to merge into and merge whatever you branch you want into it. In your case:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge develop
```

Based on your comments, I'd like to tell you that indeed `develop` and `origin/develop` are two separate branches. They are as separate as any other two randomly picked branches can be, except perhaps that `develop` might be tracking `origin/develop`, but that's just a minor convenience.

If you do `git branch --all`, you will see a list of all branches, which are either in the form `some_branch` which means they are a local branch or `some_remote/some_branch` which means they are a *local* copy of a remote branch.

When you do, `git fetch some_remote`, you are updating local copies of branches present in `some_remote`. When you say `git merge some_remote/some_branch`, you are merging in your local version of `some_remote/some_branch` exactly the same way as `git merge some_branch` would merge your local branch.

---

Answer to original question:

You can add the development repository as a remote of the master repository:

```
# add develop as remote
$ cd /path/to/master
$ git remote add develop /path/to/develop

# update from it
$ git fetch develop
$ git merge develop/master
```

Note that a better idea would be to have a single repository with develop and master branches, but there could be specific cases where having two copies would also be necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ask the question correctly... please see UPDATE above>